# Meaning of 1% precision

Tags: rounding-error, significant-figures

Suppose I calculated the numerical value of $ln(1.1)$ using Taylor expansion of $ln(1+x)$ and got $0.095333.....$, by expanding up to the fourth term. Now if somebody asks me to write the answer with a 1% precision, what does it mean? Does it mean $1\% = 0.01$, so round it to 2 decimal place or up to how many terms I expand as here I have expanded till third derivative or something else?

Comment: I would interpret it to mean two significant figures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: But, is it also something to do with up tp how many terms I expand?

Comment: You have to tell us exactly what somebody asked you to do.

Comment: Ok the question is to use the general formula for taylor expansion to find the numerical value of ln(1.1) with a 1% precision.

Comment: Well, you can check it numerically, yourself! We can quickly check that $\ln 1.1 \approx 0.09531= x$. Therefore, we want the answer $y$ to be so that its interpretation has the feature
$$
0.99x < y < 1.01 x
$$
Evaluating the limits, you get $0.09436$ for the lower limit and $0.09626$ for the upper limit. Therefore, it's clear that $y$ should have two significant figures in order to fulfill ths condition.